# Elasticsearch DSL query for both nested field and normal field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-nested

I need help to write a query to filter document with below structure

```
{
"enviID" : 123,
"empID" : 456,
"projects" : [{"id": 123, "name":"abc"},{"id": 456, "name":"xyz"}],
tests : [{"id": 999, "name":"xxx"},{"id": 000, "name":"yyy"}]
}
```

I want to filter on

```
envId, empId, project.Id, tests.id
```

also I am checking mapping document that tests field is not mapped but documents have this field

Comment: what sort of filters do you want to apply to the fields that you have mentioned? Can u be a little more specific

Answer (score 0):

> i want to filter on envId, empId, project.Id, tests.id

**Since, you have not specified any particular filter that you want to apply to the fields, the search query shown below filters the documents based on their `Id`**

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "enviID": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "empID": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "projects": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "tests": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "enviID": {
                    "value": "123"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "empID": {
                    "value": "456"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "projects",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "projects.id": 123
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "tests",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "tests.id": 999
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "enviID": 123,
                    "empID": 456,
                    "projects": [
                        {
                            "id": 123,
                            "name": "abc"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 456,
                            "name": "xyz"
                        }
                    ],
                    "tests": [
                        {
                            "id": 999,
                            "name": "xxx"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "name": "yyy"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

You can refer this to know more about [Query-filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) and [Nested Query filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

Comment: @Ashu did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)